# FaIconLibrary not found when using angular-fontawesome and font-awesome 5

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

I have the following error when trying to use `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` in my angular 7 application:

```
node_modules/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/angular-fontawesome"' has no exported member 'FaIconLibrary
```

I followed the documentation and initialized the module this way:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
(...)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    (...)
    FontAwesomeModule,
    (...)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.add(...icons);
  }
}
```

Here are the exact version I use:

```
"@angular/core": "7.2.2",
(...)
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.11.2",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.21",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "5.10.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.10.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.10.1",
```

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see [release notes](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/releases), FaIconLibrary is added from version 0.5.0 that is not compatible with angular 7.2.2. Then you should use old way for adding icons, for e.g:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faSquare, faCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faSquare as farSquare, faCheckSquare as farCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { faStackOverflow, faGithub, faMedium } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'; 

...

export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    library.add(faSquare, faCheckSquare, farSquare, farCheckSquare, faStackOverflow, faGithub, faMedium);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Solved the problem. Thanks!